# How to resolve BUILD FAILURE project tutorial DevKit mulesoft

Tags: maven, mule-studio

I'm trying to use for the first time DevKit of mulesoft, I'm following the guide of mulesoft at link: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Tutorial+-+Barn+Connector. I have installed  DevKit Plugin from Mule studio and after that I have tried to create the Anypoint Connector Project like the guide said me, but I have found the problem with Maven. 
My error is:

```
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to codehaus-plugin-snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org): Connect to http-proxy.xxx.com:80 [http-proxy.xxx.com/xxx] failed: Connection timed out: connect
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to mulesoft-plugin-releases (http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/): Connect to http-proxy.xxx.com:80 [http-proxy.xxx.com/xxx] failed: Connection timed out: connect
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to mulesoft-plugin-snapshots (http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/): Connect to http-proxy.xxx.com:80 [http-proxy.xxx.com/xxx] failed: Connection timed out: connect
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to http-proxy.xxx.com:80 [http-proxy.xxx.com/xxx] failed: Connection timed out: connect
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:27 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-11T13:05:19+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/223M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\s\.m2\repository), codehaus-plugin-snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org), mulesoft-plugin-releases (http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/), mulesoft-plugin-snapshots (http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginVersionResolutionException
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Fix your connection timeouts `Connect to http-proxy.xxx.com:80 [http-proxy.xxx.com/xxx] failed: Connection timed out: connect`....

Comment: I reloved the problem fixing with comment the proxy in the file settings.xml of Maven and in addition to setting Window->Preferences->Installations: apache-maven-3.2.5 and User Settings: the file settings.xml to the path: C:\apache-maven-3.2.5\conf\settings.xml. Now it works.

Comment: You shouldn't change the Maven installation `apache-maven-3.2.5\conf\settings.xml` better use the settings.xml file in your home folder $USER/.m2/settings.xml . If you update Maven you don't need to change a thing.

Comment: The project has downloaded all repository but at the end the Console of MuleStudio has given me the following error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project barn-connector: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.mule.modules:barn-connector:mule-module:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact net.java.dev.stax-utils:stax-utils:jar:20080702 from/to codehaus-mule-repo (http://repository.codehaus.org): Connect to repository.codehaus.org:80 [repository.codehaus.org/199.193.192.103] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]

Comment: I have retried to recreate the project and now it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something happened when maven was downloading the dependencies, try generating another new connector.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check for the existence of Maven JAR with the specified version?